# Задача с контеста, комментарии ревьюера

Tags: python, decode

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей на яндекс контесте, не понятно, как реализовать доработку ревьюера.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен содержать суть проблемы. Сам вопрос должен быть описан текстом. Код в вопросе должен быть в текстовом виде, а не скриншотом. Вопрос будет закрыт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала разберёмся с терминологией. Упрощённо:

- Метод — это функция в классе
- Атрибут — это переменная в классе

У вас всего один класс — `Dek`. И ревьюер хочет, чтобы вы в него добавили функцию `is_full`:

```py
class Dek:
    def is_full(self):
        self._size >= len(self._data)
```

Далее ревьюер просит вас добавить переменную `max_size`. Он считает, что лучше не вызывать функцию `len` каждый раз при проверке условия (максимальный размер уже не изменится):

```py
class Dek:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self._max_size = max_size

    def is_full(self):
        self._size >= self._max_size
```

И, конечно, вы должны использовать только что созданный метод:

```py
class Dek:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self._max_size = max_size

    def is_full(self):
        self._size >= self._max_size

    def _push(self, i, di, value):
        if self.is_full():
            raise OverflowError
```

Comment: "P.S.: Колода по-английски Deck" - тут подразумевается структура данных "дэк" - двусторонняя очередь, но по английски она пишется "deque" (что-то типа акронима от Double Ended Queue)

Comment: @insolor Спасибо! Должно быть `Deque`, и правда